# Cayley graphs of Abelian groups quasi-isometrically embeddable in R^d

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Are all Cayley graphs of ${\mathbb Z}^d$ quasi-isometrically embeddable in ${\mathbb R}^d$? Or, else, do they all have the same growth exponent? Is it the same true for all finitely-generated Abelian groups?

Comment: At first glance, the question seems silly/stupid/obvious. But then it's not clear that all Cayley graphs of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^2$ are actually planar!

Comment: If the generating set $S$ for $\mathbb{Z}$ is taken to be redundant (e.g. $\{\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3 \}$) then the Cayley graph cannot be embedded.

Comment: @J.Martel: it's clear that some Cayley graphs of $\mathbb{Z}$ (wrt finite generating sets) are not planar, but it's not the question.

Comment: @Yves: it sounds like the question to me if we're talking about q.i. embeddings, and not q.i. quasi-embeddings (like in the sense of Gromov-Hausdorff distance).

Comment: I have only 1 meaning of q.i. embeddings in mind, namely a map $f$ satisfying $c^{-1}d(x,y)+c'\le d(f(x),f(y))\le cd(x,y)+c'$ for all $x,y$, and fixed constants $c\ge 1$ and $c'\ge 0$. For this meaning, the answer to the question is trivially yes (assuming as people usually do that all Cayley graphs are wrt finite generating subsets): just consider the identity embedding of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ into $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: We are theoretical physicists recently got involved in geometric group theory. We will reformulate the question in a more detailed way on MathOverflow. @J.Martel, it would be helpful if you can give us a reference for the distinction between q.i. embedding and q.i. quasi-embedding.

Comment: why don't you just edit the question here?

Comment: This will not make confusion? The answers, will be then related to a different question, right?

Comment: It depends if you reformulate the question or ask another one... also maybe rather ask the new question here on math stack exchange, if it's not a research question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to all questions is yes. Fix a finite generating subset $S$ for $\mathbf{Z}^d$ and endow $\mathbf{Z}^d$ with the word metric $d_S$.

1) The inclusion of $(\mathbf{Z}^d,d_S)$ into $\mathbf{R}^d$ (the latter being endowed with any norm) is a q.i. embedding.

2) The growth exponent of $(\mathbf{Z}^d,d_S)$ is $d$.

3) The same holds for any f.g. abelian group, say $\mathbb{Z}^d\times F$ for $F$ finite. Its growth exponent is $d$. A q.i. embedding is given by mapping $(v,f)\in \mathbb{Z}^d\times F$ to $v+u(f)\in\mathbf{R}^d$ where $u$ is any function $F\to\mathbf{R}^d$ (e.g. the zero function). If you want an injective q.i. embedding just choose $u$ more carefully, e.g. take $f$ to be injective with image contained in $[0,1/2\mathclose[^d$.